# Suggestions on implementing PHP object between database

Tags: php, database, object

Here is something I would like to do:

```
User:
id
first_name
second_name
gender
```

and I make a php Object "User", and I modify the "User"'s attribute, I update the database, for example,

```
$aUser->setGender("M");
```

in the set gender, I execute an update statement using php... But I got a problems here, if the user only have 4 attributes, it is ok for me to write one by one. But if the object have many attributes, I need to write more update statement....(I can write a general update statement, whatever I change which attribute, I update all the attribute once, but I think it is no point to do so.. ... ) How can I simplify that? Thank you.

Comment: I do this myself by having a `save()` method which I call at the appropriate time, but there is probably a better answer out there.

Comment: I would say that it's extremely inefficient to update the database after every attribute update.  Instead, I suggest you have one "update" method in your object and call it when all attributes are set.  This way, you have only 1 database call making it a lot more efficient.

Comment: really, but will it not necessary to update non-modify attribute again?

Comment: I'd do as Aleks G suggests. It's much more efficient to run a single update, possibly with non-modified attributes, than to update the attributes one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments of the question suggests it: You should use a method like `save()` from time to time, instead of querying the database every time anything changes.

Personally I don't see a problem in updating every column, even if the corresponding property didn't changed. However, you can save the original values in another (array) property and then compare the values against each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function like the following (similar to what others are suggesting):

> $aUser->setValues(array("gender" =>
>   "M", "first_name" => "Steve"));

Then that function can reference your object variables to check and see if they're different and run the update.  Or just run the update with the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use an object relational mapper. What you're doing sounds like it would be served best by [RedBean](http://redbeanphp.com/community/wiki/index.php/Tutorial).